# apache redirect based on query string

Tags: apache, redirect, query-string

I want to setup two redirection based on query string

1. www.example.com/catalouge/browse.do?cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=Z1

has to redirect to:

www.example.com/books/cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=en

2. www.example.com/catalouge/browse.do?cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=Z2

has to redirect to:

www.example.com/books/cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=in

I added the following into my configuration file

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=Z1
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/browse.do$ http://www.example.com/books/cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=en [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=Z2
RewriteRule ^/catalogue/browse.do$ http://www.example.com/books/cat_id=XYZ&scp_id=in [L,R=301]
```

Is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you looking for other alternative ways? Isn't your current code working?